# How to save the summarise data into a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm currently using the `group_by()` function and `summaraise()` to get the sum of my columns, is it possible to save that information to another data frame somehow? Maybe even create a csv file with its information. Thanks

```
workday %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric) %>% summarise(across(Axis1:New_Sitting,sum))
```

Comment: `new_data <- workday %>% group_by(Date) %>%....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the pipe result in a new object, say `a`

`a <- workday %>% group_by(Date) %>% #other ops on workday`

To save it to a file there are several options, including the base `write.csv`:

`write.csv(a, "Path to file")`